check if image has "out of focus" blur or "motion blur" problem
I have bunch of images. i want check programatically if they have motion blur vs. out of focus problem. I know the images with motion blur have a directionality /correlation.
I tried using Fourier transform to detect motion blur and the variance of laplacian (usin Python) for  out of focus. Can anyone suggest better approaches?

keeps getting asked. I CBA to pick a canonical question. -- sensible approaches: laplacian pyramid or fourier transform -- motion blur is a specific type. its "point spread function" isn't circular.

Do you have many examples, are many of them labeled?

Nope, none of my examples are labeled.

[mre] required, which on these tags means you should at least show us some pictures. you clearly have some idea how to approach this, so show us your attempt and the results. [ask]
